# How do I create a picklist from a given collection in a flow?

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, picklist

I have a flow in which I eventually get a collection of contacts.
I want to display all of those contacts in a picklist which saves the ID of the selected contact for further business logic.
My main issue is with the JavaScript part as I am fairly new to all of this. For now this is what I have:

**.HTML**

```
<template>
    <label for="picklist">{labelPicklist}</label>
      <select id="picklist" class="select uiInput uiInputSelect uiInput--default uiInput--select" onchange={handleChange} >
        <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
          <template for:each={options} for:item="option">
              <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
          </template>
      </select>       
  </template>
```

**.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="objectName" type="String" role="inputOnly"/>
            <property name="recordTypeId" type="String" role="inputOnly"/>
            <property name="fieldName" type="String" role="inputOnly"/>
            <property name="labelPicklist" type="String" role="inputOnly"/>
            <property name="picklistChoise" type="String" role="outputOnly"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

As for the JS, I saw those imports being used and the HandleChange method but I'm not sure how to proceed:

**.JS**

```
import { LightningElement, wire,api,track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValuesByRecordType, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class FlowCollectionPicklist extends LightningElement {
    handleChange(event) {
        this.picklistChoise = event.srcElement.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't currently be done in the official Flow product. Building it from scratch like you're doing above is impressive but if you want to just install a component that does it for you, try the  [Quick Choice](https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/) extension.